# Knockout's purecomputed equivalent in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js

From my understanding of [this article](http://www.jomendez.com/2015/02/06/knockoutjs-computed-equivalent-angularjs/), (and please correct me if I'm wrong) Angular's two way binding model using $watch is equivalent to Knockout's computed observables.

According to the KnockoutJS documentation, [pure computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) prevent memory leaks and reduce CPU overhead. Does AngularJS have an equivalent?

I'm not very proficient with either Knockout or Angular but have used both very briefly. Now, lets say that I have an existing application using KnockbackJS which I want to move to AngularJS. Now I have the things like routing and templating covered, but What would I do for all the instances where purecomputed is being used?

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS 1.x and KnockoutJS are similar, yet very different. Concerning your question, they are actually wildly different: Angular uses a digest cycle for change detection, where KnockoutJS uses a subscription-based approach under the cover.

Yes, *watches* in Angular look a lot like *computeds* from KnockoutJS, because they allow you to do a manual "subscription" which is checked during each digest cycle.

That is also where comparing apples and oranges starts to loose its potency. The difference between a `computed` and a `pureComputed` is a technical detail of KnockoutJS. AFAIK there is no direct equivalent of that in AngularJS, or perhaps you could argue that a watch *is* the equivalent.

Most likely you have an XY-problem, where you know how to solve X in KnockoutJS: with computeds and pureComputeds. Don't try to translate Y to AngularJS, but try to translate X to your new situation, and find an idiomatic way to solve that with AngularJS instead.